# How to hide the bootstrap multiselect hover tooltip?

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-multiselect

I am using the bootstrap multiselect plugin provided by http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/. I am facing problem with the hover over tooltip with all selected values. It displays unexpected results like in given image.[tootip unexpected results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtQ7z.jpg)
I want to remove the tooltip I have also tried to disable the button title attribute whoes value is displayed in the tooltip. but it doesn't work. 
My current code is like this. 
**Current HTML with PHP Code:**

```
<select class="form-control" multiple name="speciality[]" id="speciality">
<?php if($data=$user->getAllSpecialities()){
    foreach($data as $key => $value) {?>
        <option selected value="<?php echo $value['speciality_id'];?>">
                <?php echo $value['speciality_title'];?> 
        </option>
    <?php }
 }?>
</select>
```

**Jquery with multiselect initialization:**

```
$('#speciality').multiselect({
    nonSelectedText: 'Select Speciality',
    numberDisplayed: 2,
    buttonClass: 'btn btn-default',
    buttonWidth: '100%',
    includeSelectAllOption: true,
    allSelectedText:'All',              
    selectAllValue: 0,
    selectAllNumber: false,
    maxHeight: 100,
    onSelectAll: function() {
        $('button[class="multiselect"]').attr('title',false);
    }
});
//$('#speciality').tooltip().attr('title', 'all specialities');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood yor question properly then your willing to remove the tool tip then try this

```
<select class="form-control" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left" multiple name="speciality[]" id="speciality">
<?php if($data=$user->getAllSpecialities()){
foreach($data as $key => $value) {?>
    =<option selected value="<?php echo $value['speciality_id'];?>">
            <?php echo $value['speciality_title'];?> 
    </option>
<?php } }?></select>
```

to remove tooltip use this code`

```
$('#speciality').tooltip('hide')
```

Or

```
$('#speciality').tooltip('destroy')
```

Comment: Dear Aditya, i have tried both solutions that you suggested but it's not working still getting the same results.

Comment: are u using tool tip in that select tag or not can u show me that code

Answer (score 6):

To remove tooltip you need to override buttonTitle function in your options.

```
$('#speciality').multiselect({
nonSelectedText: 'Select Speciality',
numberDisplayed: 2,
buttonClass: 'btn btn-default',
buttonWidth: '100%',
includeSelectAllOption: true,
allSelectedText:'All',              
selectAllValue: 0,
selectAllNumber: false,
maxHeight: 100,
onSelectAll: function() {
    $('button[class="multiselect"]').attr('title',false);
},
buttonTitle: function() {},
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this!

Comment: I think this is a better solution. Thumbs up

Answer (score 2):

I think I found answer myself. I removed the title attribute of the button that was being displayed as tooltip. My revised code is here. 
**Revised JQuery Code**

```
$('#speciality').multiselect({
    nonSelectedText: 'Select Speciality',
    numberDisplayed: 2,
    buttonClass: 'btn btn-default',
    buttonWidth: '100%',
    includeSelectAllOption: true,
    allSelectedText:'All',              
    selectAllValue: 0,
    selectAllNumber: false,
    maxHeight: 100,
    onDropdownHidden: function(event) {
         // to remove the title when dropdown is hidden so we can remove the title generated by the plugin
         $('button[class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default"]').removeAttr("title"); 
    }
});

$('button[class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default"]').removeAttr("title");
```

Answer (score 0):

In Js part
this code works for me

```
 $('.multi-selectpicker').multiselect({
      includeSelectAllOption: true,
      enableFiltering: true,
      nonSelectedText: 'Select Groups',
      buttonTitle: function() {},
 });
 $('button[class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default"]').removeAttr("title");
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).on('mouseover','.multiselect ',function(){ $(this).removeAttr('title'); });`